# How to select in rails method using previous find array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I want to find array, but gow can i do this?

```
@model = Model.find(:first, :conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => params[:man]}) 
@ct = CountryDesignation.find(:first, :conditions => { :CDS_ID => "110000002"})
```

but :CDS_ID => "110000002" is not good. I need to select it via @model.Field, for example: :CDS_ID => @model.Field. But also @model is not just one entry, it's an array. So I need for every Model select CountryDesignation. 
But then I need to select from CountryDesignation array DesText array

> @destext = DesText.find(:all, :conditions => { :TEX_ID => @ct.Field})

How to do this work?
And how to correct view this?

> ```
> %table
>   %tr
>     %th Mfa id
>     %th Год начала выпуска
>     %th Год завершения выпуска
>   - @model.each do |model| 
>     %tr
>       %td= link_to model.MOD_ID, model
>       %td= link_to model.MOD_PCON_START, model
>       -if model.MOD_PCON_END.blank?
>         %td= link_to "По настоящее время", model
>       -else
>         %td= link_to model.MOD_PCON_END, model
>       -#%td= model.country_designations.des_texts.TEX_TEXT
>       -#= link_to 'Show model', model
>   %br
>   - @destext.each do |t|
>     name
>     %td= t.TEX_ID
>     %td= t.TEX_TEXT
>   - @ct.each do |ct|
>     ct
>     %td= ct.CDS_ID
>     %td= ct.CDS_TEX_ID
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`. If the model attribute you're interested in were named `cds_id`:

```
@models = Model.all(:conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => params[:man] })
@ct = CountryDesignation.all(:conditions => { :CDS_ID => @models.map(&:cds_id) })
```

This essentially grabs the `cds_id` attribute of each model into an array and uses those values in a SQL `IN` clause. It returns an array of `CountryDesignation` objects that match.

Comment: hm, no, I need field MOD_CDS_ID, so :CDS_ID => @models.MOD_CDS_ID like this

Comment: Okay, then just replace `cds_id` with `MOD_CDS_ID` in my example. I don't know what what your models look like, so I'm just giving an example.

Comment: like this all trouble is existing db(((

Comment: COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS has_many MODELS 

DES_TEXTS has_many COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS 

MANUFACTURERS has_many MODELS

Comment: how can i format this it in view, so that every model displays it ct and destext fields?

Comment: and what to do if ct always have uniq if, but one of it's field reffers to des_text, and this field can be equal for many ct.id

Comment: See, table MODELS has field MOD_CDS_ID, with this field I go to table COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS and it's field CDS_ID = MOD_CDS_ID (from MODELS table), than from this table I select field CDS_TEX_ID and go with this id to table DES_TEXTS it's field TEX_ID must be equal from previous table CDS_TEX_ID, and fetch field TEX_TEXT !!! And this field in my iteration @model.each do.... i must display for every model.

Comment: Please refrain from posting excessive detail in comments. You should update your original question with these additional constraints, or perhaps open a new question if the subject matter is substantially different. I'm not even sure what you're asking anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a way for ActiveRecord to handle the array in the same manner as an IN clause in SQL. Luckily, AR does that by default when passed an array. In other words, you should be able to write:

@model = Model.find(:first, :conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => })

Comment: Oops, bad formatting. There was supposed to be an array before the closing }

Comment: Pavel, my solution is essentially the same as what you got from Brandan. In other words, to fit your problem, the answer will still be: `CountryDesignation.all(:conditions => { :CDS_ID => @models.map(&:MOD_CSD_ID) })`

Comment: and what to do if ct always have uniq if, but one of it's field reffers to des_text, and this field can be equal for many ct.id

Comment: how can i format this it in view, so that every model displays it ct and destext fields?

Comment: Are you asking how to get unique des_text rows based on the values in ct? Try: `@destext = DesText.find(:all, :conditions => { :TEX_ID => @ct.map(&:Field).uniq})` ...This will result in an array of keys that are unique. Also, I would suggest reading up on ActiveRecord associations - it looks like there's a lot of overlap between what you're trying to do and associations.

Comment: not uniq! all tutorials are simple, but this db is realy huge!

Comment: for example for ten models if fetch only GAS and Diesel, but every model is only Gas, or only diesel

Comment: See, table MODELS has field MOD_CDS_ID, with this field I go to table COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS and it's field CDS_ID = MOD_CDS_ID (from MODELS table), than from this table I select field CDS_TEX_ID and go with this id to table DES_TEXTS it's field TEX_ID must be equal from previous table CDS_TEX_ID, and fetch field TEX_TEXT !!! And this field in my iteration @model.each do.... i must display for every model.